# "Unrolling" a string with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, string, exslt

We have an application which has a heirarchical group structure. Some of the groups are passed in this format:

```
/Geography/NA/US/California
```

I would like to "unroll" this string so that I can get a node set like the following:

```
/Geography
/Geography/NA
/Geography/NA/US
/Geography/NA/US/California
```

I know I can use [str:tokenize](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) and get a nodeset like so: `[Geography, NA, US, California]` but I'm at a loss of how to assemble the parts back together incrementally.

I have most of the [exslt](http://www.exslt.org/) functions available to use, but no XSLT 2.0 functions.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy in plain XSLT 1.0, all you need is a recursive function like so:

```
<xsl:template name="UnrollString">
  <xsl:param name="string" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="head"   select="'/'" />

  <xsl:variable name="tail" select="
    concat(
      substring-after($string, $head), 
      '/'
    )
  " />
  <xsl:variable name="lead" select="
    concat(
      $head, 
      substring-before($tail, '/')
    )
  " />

  <xsl:if test="not($tail = '/')">
    <token>
      <xsl:value-of select="$lead" />
    </token>

    <xsl:call-template name="UnrollString">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string" />
      <xsl:with-param name="head"   select="concat($lead, '/')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Output for `'/Geography/NA/US/California'` is:

```
<token>/Geography</token>
<token>/Geography/NA</token>
<token>/Geography/NA/US</token>
<token>/Geography/NA/US/California</token>
```

Note that:

- The function expects the string to start with a delimiter (i.e. a slash), or the first word ('Geography') will be missing in the output.
- A single trailing slash is ignored.
- The delimiter cold easily be generalized and passed in as a parameter.
- You could build a hierarchy easily by placing the recursive call into the `<token>` element instead of outside.
- The output order can be reversed (longest to shortest) by placing the recursive call above the `<token>` element instead of below it.
- You would need to use the `node-set()` extension function to convert the returned tokens into something that can be used further.

Comment: This is great! This is just what I was looking for. Thank you! Bonus points if you can tell me how to drop the "/Geography" token while keeping the rest of the tokens ("/Geography/NA", for example).

Comment: You could wrap the `token` into an `xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($lead, '/'), '/')"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize it, then write a recursive template that [concatenates](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/concat/index.html) together only the pieces you're interested in. (I'm not going to sit down and write this right now, but I'd use a combination of XPath and [set:leading](http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/leading/index.html) to produce first the full nodeset, then all but the last node, then all but the last two nodes, and so on and so forth -- you'll be passing the full nodeset and whatever node you stripped off most recently as the template params at each recursion, until you reach the beginning of the nodeset.)

Happily, this is a nice simple factorial-like recursion, not something hideous like the Fibonacci sequence.